# hadoop too many logs on screen

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive

I start learning hadoop using hive recently. As a beginner I am not so familiar with all the logs showing on the screen. So it's better to see a clean version of all important logs. I learn hive based on Rutberglen's "`Programming Hive`" book.

Just started, and I got numerous of logs after the first command. While on the book, it's just "OK, Time taken: 3.543 seconds".

Anyone has solution to reduce these logs?

PS:below are the logs I got from command "`create table x (a int);`"

```
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use    org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:28 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf <clinit>
WARNING: hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/Users/admin/Documents/Study/software    /Programming/Hive/hive-0.9.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.9.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:28 AM SessionState printInfo
INFO: Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/Users/admin/Documents/Study/software/Programming/Hive/hive-0.9.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.9.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/admin/hive_job_log_admin_201409280010_720612579.txt
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:28 AM hive.ql.exec.HiveHistory printInfo
INFO: Hive history file=/tmp/admin/hive_job_log_admin_201409280010_720612579.txt
hive> CREATE TABLE x (a INT);
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogBegin
INFO: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogBegin
INFO: <PERFLOG method=compile>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver parse
INFO: Parsing command: CREATE TABLE x (a INT)
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver parse
INFO: Parse Completed
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer analyzeInternal
INFO: Starting Semantic Analysis
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer analyzeCreateTable
INFO: Creating table x position=13
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver compile
INFO: Semantic Analysis Completed
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver getSchema
INFO: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogEnd
INFO: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1411877431127 end=1411877431388 duration=261>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogBegin
INFO: <PERFLOG method=Driver.execute>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver execute
INFO: Starting command: CREATE TABLE x (a INT)
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM hive.ql.exec.DDLTask createTable
INFO: Default to LazySimpleSerDe for table x
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM hive.log getDDLFromFieldSchema
INFO: DDL: struct x { i32 a}
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore newRawStore
INFO: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:31 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore initialize
INFO: ObjectStore, initialize called
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:32 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore getPMF
INFO: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with    hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:32 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore setConf
INFO: Initialized ObjectStore
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:33 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore logInfo
INFO: 0: create_table: db=default tbl=x
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogEnd
INFO: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1411877431389 end=1411877434527 duration=3138>
OK
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver printInfo
INFO: OK
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogBegin
INFO: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogEnd
INFO: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1411877434529 end=1411877434529 duration=0>
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver PerfLogEnd
INFO: </PERFLOG method=Driver.run start=1411877431126 end=1411877434530 duration=3404>
Time taken: 3.407 seconds
Sep 28, 2014 12:10:34 AM CliDriver printInfo
INFO: Time taken: 3.407 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting hive shell as follows :

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=WARN,console
```

If you wanted to make this change persistent, modify the logger property file `HIVE_CONF_DIR/hive-log4j.properties` file. If you don't have this file in your HIVE_CONF_DIR, create this file by copying the contents of hive-log4j.default in the `HIVE_CONF_DIR`.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried the command and the issue remains. A single drop table process returns about 100 lines of logs

Comment: If needed you can up the log level to ERROR or FATAL from WARN, so that all WARN messages will be skipped.

Comment: Tried also. But as you can see, most of the logs are INFO. They remain there.

Comment: @Kenny I experienced the same problem, hive 2.1.1 with hadoop 2.7.3. Have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: Exact this solution. And this is general way for many distributed frameworks.